# Retrieve data EXEC SQL for temp table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to retrieve the data from usage of EXEC SQL and paste the data inside of a temp table?

If yes, can you possible show me? I have a sample of data in this link

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/68214/1/0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.  Create your temp table.  Then use the insert into statement to insert the results of an exec statement into it:

```
create table #datatable (id int,
                        name varchar(100),
                        email varchar(10),
                        phone varchar(10),
                        cellphone varchar(10),
                        none varchar(10)                        
                       );

insert into #datatable
exec ('select *
from datatable
where id = 1') 

select * from #datatable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use INSERT INTO EXEC clause.

```
INSERT INTO  #tmp
EXEC sp_executesql (@q)
```